# ¿cuales son los archivos esenciales de bootstrap?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap

hola he estado probando a quitar enlaces del header y he comprobado que todos estes los podia quitar sin observar cambios en la pagina:

```
<script src="jsBootstrap/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsBootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

en cambio este otro si lo quito me desordena toda la pagina:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Es lógico que si quites el último se desordene toda la página, pues son **todos** los estilos de bootstrap, los demás son algunos complementos recomendados que se deja a elección de el usuario

Comment: La documentación es clara: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Reafirmo lo que dice @mafu, la documentacion es clara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap es un framework css, por lo que el archivo css es imprescindible para su utilizo ya que es el que contiene todos los estilos.

Los otros archivos js son necesarios solo en determinados casos. Jquery es necesario solo si debes usar uno de los otros dos archivos js de Bootstrap ya que estos utilizan jquery, por lo que dependen de él.

Ahora, si no recuerdo mal: Popper es usado para cosas como modals y popups, mientras que bootstrap.js es necesario para cosas como por ejemplo abrir o cerrar un navbar (versión móvil)

Comment: De hecho, todo lo que dices esta en la [documentacion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), esto significa que el OP no lo leyo, porque de entender es muy claro

Comment: Supuse que no sabía ingles.

Comment: Como observación, [jQuery ya no es necesario](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#still-want-to-use-jquery-its-possible) en la version 5 de Bootstrap y Popper.js se puede unificar en el [Bundle JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle) de Bootstrap. Buena respuesta

Comment: Gracias Jheyman, hasta yo aprendí algo nuevo.